# Laravel 5.4 and HTTP_Request2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, httprequest, laravel-5.4

So I have already installed pear/http_request2 on my laravel project but can't seem to make it work. What I'm trying is the following code for the Bing Image Search API:

```
    $request = new \Http_Request2('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search');
    $url = $request->getUrl();

    $headers = array(
        // Request headers
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '{subscription key}',
    );

    $request->setHeader($headers);

    $parameters = array(
        'q' => 'query string',
    );

    $url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

    $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);

    $request->setBody("{body}");

    try
    {
        $response = $request->send();
        $response->getBody();
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
        $ex;
    }
```

Whenever I call it on my controller, I get a "Class 'Http_Request2' not found" error. How, in any way, can I use the pear/http_request2 for my project?

UPDATE: Solution

I've found out that I have the use the base_path for a non-Laravel package to be used.

I added

```
require_once $path = base_path('vendor/pear/http_request2/HTTP/Request2.php');
```

and it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take a look at the end user documentation for HTTP_Request2 available here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.intro.php, I can see an example use case with the code beggining like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new HTTP_Request2('http://pear.php.net/', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
```

You can try first including HTTP_Request2 using line "require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';", and then make new HTTP_Request2 instance.

The thing is that Laravel uses PSR-4 autoloading provided by Composer package, but HTTP_Request2 doesn't work in that way. But, using require_once() in your code should work in Laravel without problems. Just make sure to use the right path to the Request2.php file.

Comment: Okay will try this and get back to you in a bit.